# Is Adobe Air/Flash the easiest framework for advanced GUI development?

Tags: user-interface, air, webbrowser-control

Excuse a non-developer being forced to develop applications instead of administrating networks like I'm used to. This is a horrible post in many ways.

I'm developing an application which has reached the point of needing a GUI. However, I haven't done any GUI development ever before, so I feel the need to ask for help on this.

The application is your standard data collecting/management app, with all common widgets and stuff that every application is using. The problem is that I need the application to be able to display websites using an external browser of some sort, to pass a captcha on the site the application works against. The website guys haven't given me permission to circumvent the captcha in any way.

I know of GTK, QT, Tcl/Tk etc. None of these frameworks have struck me as easy to use. To be honest, I'd like to design the interface using drag-and-drop like I used to do in VB6 when I was a kid, although I get chills thinking about writing this thing in Basic.

I was thinking about Adobe Air, and to design the application in Flash/ActionScript. From what I've learned about Air, I should be able to do everything I want to do. And I do believe it has built in sqlite, right? Would it be considered more "simple" to develop the actual GUI using Flash than using one of the traditional frameworks? What pitfalls am I facing?

A few guidelines:

- It only needs to run on Windows
- I need to be able to work against a database. Currently using SQLite3.
- Some sort of browser integration is crucial. A browser window of some sort needs to open up *inside* my interface, be directed by the application, and the application needs to be able to read some data from the site that is being used.

Any help with this would be great. This is a clear case where I have to rely on the experience of others to complete the project at all. I'm happy to provide more information if you need that to make a suggestion.

Comment: Questions about "best" and "easiest" generally don't belong here, because it's a subjective judgement.  The easiest one is usually the one you know best.

Comment: GTK has an graphical interface builder, Glade; Qt ditto, Qt Designer. From my experience with using both I would say that Glade is fairly good, Qt Designer is excellent. (And both have WebKit controls.)

Answer (score 0):

You can always try Titanium Framework, it was aquired by Appcelerator nor so much ago. http://www.appcelerator.com/
It actually puts a webkit browser in a window, so if you can design HTML and CSS you can use this framework.